# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '`${string}` | `${string}.${string}` | `${string}.${number}`'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I've migrated `react-hook-forms` from v.6 to v.7.

After changing the `register` method, as pointed out in the [migration guide](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/), the following error occurs:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '`${string}` | `${string}.${string}` | `${string}.${number}`'.  TS2345

Register expects a string name, which I provide correctly with a param which for sure is a string, but anyhow it doesn't accept my parameter if I don't pass exactly string.

Anyone with a similar issue or any idea is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm running into this error while trying to set a dynamic name on a Controller. Can you add a code snippet of the parameter you are using in the `register` method?

Answer (score 12):

[`register()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register#registerRef) in `react-hook-form` v7 does not accept a string but *string [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types)*. The literal value is one of the field name in the form:

```js
interface IFormValues {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

```
const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<IFormValues>();
```

When you assign a generic type parameter to the `useForm` hook, the `register` expects to receive either `firstName` or `lastName` literal, a string or anything else will throw a type error.

### Solution

According to the [official example](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray), if you are using `useFieldArray` and the fields are created dynamically using `map`, you need to assert the name as a const before passing to the `register`, this is because of type widening when you mix string literal with the index number:

```js
<input key={field.id} {...register(`test.${index}.test` as const)}  />
```

Comment: So how do you make a string literal out of something like this, which works with v6: 
`${arrayName}[${index}].fieldName`? I've tried `${arrayName}.${index}.fieldName` based on the migration docs, but I get the same error.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66978617/9449426). @Kizmar

Comment: Get the same error when using "as const". Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Quick and dirty, but you'll notice when using "testIndex" it throws the TS error, but "otherIndex" does not. The incoming property type on my component is "number". https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-voice-30pym?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Kizmar I know the reason why. `testIndex` is a number while `otherValue` is a literal, you can create a literal by combining other literals, but you cannot mix literal with a 'generic' number type because it's not an exact value.

Comment: Right, but what's the work-around for that? My incoming index property is a 'number' type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231037/discussion-between-nearhuscarl-and-kizmar).

Comment: @Kizmar I don't really like the official example approach but it works. Updated my answer

Comment: @Kizmar - what was the outcome of your discussion? How do you work with an index of a map?

Comment: A string  literatel equates to a string so its a redundant solution and it doesn't solve the problem anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Controller, you can add conditional rendering for the name property. The error will vanish into thin air. :)

```
const textFieldData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "youtubeUrl",
    placeholder: "Youtube URL",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "videoName",
    placeholder: "Video Name",
  },
];

//form starts here
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
 {textFieldData.map((item) => {
  return (
    <Box key={item.id}>
      <Controller
       name={
       item.name === "youtubeUrl" ? "youtubeUrl" 
       : "videoName" } //<---- add conditional rendering here
       control={control}
       render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
       <TextField
       size="small"
       error={errors[item.name] ? true : false}
       fullWidth
       onChange={onChange}
       value={value}
       placeholder={item.placeholder}
       inputProps={{
       "aria-label": item.placeholder,
       }}
       />
       )}
       />
                    
   </Box>
 </form>
```