# React hook form useFieldArray typescript error on input name

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have written the following in typescript for a dynamic form

```
type FormData = {
    name: string,
    session: { name: string }[]
}

...

const { control, register, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormData>()
const { fields, insert, remove, move, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "session",
    keyName: "id"
})

...

{
    fields.map((field, index) => {
        return <div key={field.id}>
            <div>
                <label>Session {index}</label>
                <input type={"text"} {...register(`session.${index}.name`)} />
            </div>
        </div>
    })
}
```

and I get the error at the part {...register(`session.${index}.name`)}

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"session" | "name" | `session.${number}` | `session.${number}.name`' ts(2345)

The error goes away when i dont pass in FormData

```
const { control, register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in v7, `register()` accepts a literal (an exact string value) instead of a string. So change your code to:

```js
<input type={"text"} {...register(`session.${index}.name` as const)} />
```

To avoid type widening. See [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

Related question:

- [Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '`${string}` | `${string}.${string}` | `${string}.${number}`'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66967241/9449426)