# React-hook-form 7.16.0 type 'string | number' is not assignable to type string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm trying to add react hook form to a big project with typescript version 4.4.2. I found that react-hook-form is fine with this version so I pulled it and now I'm getting some typscript errors inside type definitions in node_modules:

```
node_modules/react-hook-form/dist/types/utils.d.ts:5:11 - error TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          5     [K in string | number]: never;
```

It points to this line in util.ts file:

```
export declare type EmptyObject = {
    [K in string | number]: never;
};
```

Any ideas of what to look for? Do I need to go with a higher version?

I'm using FieldArray in my code and register fields using format `test.${index}.test` as in documentation. I tried casting it to const but it does not solve my problem. I tried everything from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66967241/argument-of-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-string). I commented out all my code and found that just importing useForm gives me this error.